# What are Gateway classes and Framework Classes

Tags: java, oop

To give you an overview, our project is webapp using other modules we also created (cdi, dal, utility, services).

Now I was asked to list all gateway classes and framework classes. Is it correct that the gateway classes are the interfaces/classes used by webapp to access the other modules (cdi, dal...)? and framework classes are simply the classes of the modules?

In a nutshell, what is framework class and gateway class?

I would appreciate if you can give references that I can read about these (yeah I know RTFM but i don't know where to start.)

So you might wonder why don't ask the one that gave me the task (12 hours time difference). Also even I dont hit the target, atleast I will learn something today :)

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the terms you used are formal terms. The way I understand it is something like:

**Gateway classes** - The classes that conduct your API, then entry points to your application. For example, you said that your project is a webapp, so your controller class, your servlets, are the gateway classes. Those are the classes that allow to interact and start flows of your app.

**Framework classes** - The classes that build your app. After starting a flow through your gateway classes, some logic starts to run. This logic probably consists various classes such as DAOs, Runnable, Utils and other classes that are part of the logic. Also, it consists of model classes - the classes that hold your data. All of these are you're framework classes.